# Disable iPhone X Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x

Is there anyway to get the black areas back on the top and bottom of the iPhone x constraints. I want to push an update out but havent fully fixed all the iphone X constraints. I would like to revert it back to just having the black area on top and bottom so that at least everything will look normal for now. Does anyone know how to do this ( I think when I updated xcode it got rid of it on its own)

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you have any specifics? Code? Anything?

Comment: I don't think you can build a pre-iPhone X version in current-Xcode. I'm sure there's some hacky way to do it by changing the window frame. I'd recommend doing the bare minimum to get it usable, then fix the remaining issues later.

Answer (score 2):

If you added an iPhone X-sized launch image, try removing it.  My app had the black bars on the top and bottom until I added that launch image.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the safe area insets, you might have added. Also, resize your UIView with respect to Layout Anchors, used pre ios 11.